# delete unnecessary line breaks within a paragraph in vs code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to delete unnecessary line breaks within paragraphs in vs code.

I tried `[^\n\r]([\r\n])[^\n\r]`, but I cannot figure out how to capture the right line break in vs code.

The original text is

```
Monster Magnet 和
Kyuss
那样的乐队，完美地契合了90年代早期另类金属运动的电子乐口味。即使是在
grunge 风格已经褪色，而工业和
hip-hop
的影响也开始加诸于另类金属的时候，stoner
metal 依然是进入新世纪以来深受推崇的一种风格。

 

Stoner metal is a subgenre of metal music that combines elements of doom
metal with elements of psychedelic rock and blues rock to create a
melodic yet heavy sound. Like stoner metal's close relative genre stoner
```

The expected result is

```
Monster Magnet 和 Kyuss 那样的乐队，完美地契合了90年代早期另类金属运动的电子乐口味。即使是在 grunge 风格已经褪色，而工业和 hip-hop 的影响也开始加诸于另类金属的时候，stoner metal 依然是进入新世纪以来深受推崇的一种风格。

 

Stoner metal is a subgenre of metal music that combines elements of doom metal with elements of psychedelic rock and blues rock to create a melodic yet heavy sound. Like stoner metal's close relative genre stoner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```js
(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)
```

Replace with a space. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/WCnIIf/1).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: @RyszardCzech Thanks so much for show me negative lookbehind and negative lookahead. I am wondering if I use `[^\n\r]([\r\n])[^\n\r]`, is it possible to achieve the same result?

Comment: @WZhao Maybe, yes, `(^|[^\n])\n($|[^\n])` with `$1$2` as replacement. It will fail if there are two or more consecutive lines with only a single character on them.